# What are classes and why use more than one (C#)?

Tags: c#, class

I am studying C#. As far as I understand, classes are where everything is happening. However, I have never used one more than one class in a script, nor do I know the actual definition of a class. So why have more than one class in a script and what is the definition of a class?

Comment: most systems are more than just a simple script that does one thing from start to end... if you don't need more than one class: fine, don't use more than one class

Comment: Do have a look at the .NET framework(s) and you will see many classes that are useful. Do not call c# code a 'script'!

Answer (score 1):

A type that is defined as a class is a reference type. At run time, when you declare a variable of a reference type, the variable contains the value null until you explicitly create an instance of the class by using the new operator, or assign it an object of a compatible type that may have been created elsewhere:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
//Declaring another object of the same type, assigning it the value of the first object.
MyClass mc2 = mc;
```

That is great explaining from the C# guide by Microsoft.
You can read more from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)

Answer (score 0):

Classes serve two main purposes:

- encapsulation - putting code into different locations rather than just having one great big pile of random methods
- object orientation - having *instances* of classes (or value-types, in some cases) that represent a logical *object* (or value); you typically have many different concepts in a system, and many instances of each concept - for example, you might have a class to represent a "user", a class to represent an "order", etc (rather than just having a great big pile of random bytes as the data)